# Per pixel collision depth

Tags: c#, collision-detection, monogame, per-pixel

I need to modify the code below to get the penetration depth from the per pixel collision and return it as a Vector2 to later apply it to the character position.

```
static bool IntersectPixels(Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA,
                            Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
{
    // Find the bounds of the rectangle intersection
    int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
    int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
    int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
    int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);

    // Check every point within the intersection bounds
    for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
    {
        for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
        {
            // Get the color of both pixels at this point
            Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) +
                                 (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
            Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) +
                                 (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];

            // If both pixels are not completely transparent,
            if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
            {
                // then an intersection has been found
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // No intersection found
    return false;
}
```

Edit: I need something similar to this:
https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame.Samples/blob/develop/Platformer2D/Game/RectangleExtensions.cs

The code from the link above is for getting the intersection depth between two rectangles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting a precise intersection depth in this way will make the method much more expensive. How accurate do you need this to be? We can do it more cheaply with approximations, if that can be tolerated for your use case.

Comment: The code in the link gives the correct minimum separation vector for rectangles. We could use the same code for sprites to get a conservative separation vector: it's guaranteed to separate the sprites, but it might leave a gap (inaccuracy). Whether that inaccuracy is tolerable for your game is something we do not know. Perfect accuracy would mean computing the shortest vector that brings the sprites into pixel-to-pixel contact with no overlap. Other potential approximations could include moving the sprites apart while tolerating a few pixels' overlap, or a few pixels' gap.

Comment: Hm, i understand what you mean now. I need it to be very accurate, so i would appreciate some help to modify that method.